Guidewire: what is the significance of “skip delinquency on enough equity “ field in delinquency plan?
I am not understanding the significance of “ skip delinquency on enough equity field in delinquency plan ? I am not getting any relevant answers in docs. Could someone please explain
I need to understand the functionality behind this

I am not finding much on this field either. What version of BC are you configuring? Is this a field you are seeing on the DelinquencyPlan entity? My guess is that it is an additional delinquency entry threshold that will not start a delinquency if there is sufficient equity for the policy with the late invoice.

This is not OOTB BC functionality. Check Delinquency Management Accelerator Reference Implementation.
Following is snippet from document :
The enablement of this setting prevents a delinquency plan from being triggered
when equity exists on the policy (i.e. the “Paid Through” date of the policy is greater than or equal to the date upon which
the delinquency is scheduled to be initiated).

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
